# How to get embedded resource files from dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have two ASP.NET Core 6 MVC projects. In `Project A` I add these lines of code to `ProjectA.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="wwwroot\**\*" /> 
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <StaticWebAssetBasePath Condition="$(StaticWebAssetBasePath) == ''">/path</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So all files in `wwwroot` folder are marked as "embedded resource" and in other projects, I can access them like this:

```
 <link href="/path/css/siter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have `UIConfigureOptions` class to configure those embedded resources.

```
public class UIConfigureOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<StaticFileOptions>
{
        public UIConfigureOptions(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }
    
        public void PostConfigure(string name, StaticFileOptions options)
        {
            name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

            options.ContentTypeProvider = options.ContentTypeProvider ?? new 
                FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

            if (options.FileProvider == null && Environment.WebRootFileProvider == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing FileProvider.");
            }
    
            options.FileProvider = options.FileProvider ?? Environment.WebRootFileProvider;
    
            var basePath = "wwwroot";
    
            var filesProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(GetType().Assembly, basePath);
            options.FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(options.FileProvider, filesProvider);
        }
}
```

The other project, let's call it `ProjectMain`, is going to use `Project A`.

In `program.cs` I write this :

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

ConfigureMvcParts(builder.Services, typeof(ProjectA.Areas.Sample.Controllers.HomeController));
builder.Services.ConfigureOptions(typeof(ProjectA.Models.UIConfigureOptions));

void ConfigureMvcParts(IServiceCollection services, Type containingClassType)
{
    Assembly assembly = containingClassType.Assembly;
    AssemblyPart assemblyPart = new AssemblyPart(assembly);
    EmbeddedFileProvider fileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly);
    services.AddControllersWithViews().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm => apm.ApplicationParts.Add(assemblyPart));
    services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options => options.FileProviders.Add(fileProvider));
}
```

So all the controllers and models will be added to `ProjectMain`.

If I add `Project A` using "Add project reference", this link works fine:

```
<link href="/path/css/siter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but If I add it as `dll`, the embedded resources are not working.

When I write this code:

```
string[] resourceNames = typeof(UIConfigureOptions).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

I get a list of all those embedded resources. But it looks like I can't access them physically.

Comment: Hello! I'm using a similar code in my project. But I add data as just `Resource`, not `Embedded resource`.

If you are interested in this code, please, edit your question's description)

Comment: @SLenik I need to use it as  `Embedded resource` but you can add it as a question and then answer your question. then add the Link here.  so everyone can use it

Answer (score 0):

Try ：

```
var manifestEmbeddedProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(assembly,"wwwroot");
```

......

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() { FileProvider = manifestEmbeddedProvider });
```

here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0#manifest-embedded-file-provider) related

It works well on myside whenever I enter the uri in browser or refer it in my view when I debug ProjectA:

[image]

[image]

[image: d]

Comment: I add it but doesn't work. It looks like it is a sample project.  could I have it so I can check where I went wrong? please !!!

Comment: Sorry,I don't have the permisssion to upload the sample due to the policy,I would share all steps i've tried tomorrow,hopes help

Comment: @ 
Ruikai Feng thanks. But if you have Github, you can upload it there. anyway. I am really thankful.